# How to configure Caffeine Cache with Spring

Tags: java, spring, caffeine, caffeine-cache

I have a simple Spring application. I need to implement caching onto a few services that are expensive to call each time.

I have a configuration class like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CachingConfig {

@Bean (name = "caffeineCacheManager")
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    CaffeineCacheManager cacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager("projectList", "backlog", "childProjectList", "testRun");
    cacheManager.setCaffeine(caffeineCacheBuilder());
    return cacheManager;
}

Caffeine< Object, Object > caffeineCacheBuilder() {
    return Caffeine.newBuilder()
            .initialCapacity(100)
            .maximumSize(500)
            .expireAfterAccess(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .weakKeys()
            .recordStats();
}
}
```

My `pom.xml` includes :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
        <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have one of the method that needs to be cached like this:

```
@Cacheable(value = "projectList", cacheManager = "caffeineCacheManager")
public Map<String, String> getProjectList() {
    return getProjectList(); //**SOME EXPENSIVE CALL**
}
```

Everytime I run the app I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/Caffeine`.

Here is the complete stack trace : https://textuploader.com/1eil3
I am not sure where am I doing wrong or If I am missing something.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough wrt your problem, but do note that `weakKeys` is not compatible with Spring Cache. Since that uses reference equality and Spring generates a new key object based on the method parameters, the cache will never hit.

Comment: I tried removing it but the same errors

Comment: Yes, my comment was regarding an unrelated bug in your code

Comment: Please edit your question to add the stack trace

Comment: @tgdavies. I have the stack trace link in the question

Answer (score 0):

I analyze your code and I think the problem perphaps is related with some library which has a old version of Caffeine. Check the dependency tree